# How can I get the frame of a table view cell in the coordinate space of the table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, coordinates

I have a table view with a bunch of cells in it. I want to get the frame of a cell, not in its superview's coordinate space, but in the table view's coordinate space.

A picture would probably explain this better

[image]

See the red rectangle? That is the frame of the table cell. And the blue rectangle is the frame of the table view. I want to get the red rectangle that is relative to the blue rectangle.

I tried to use the `frame` property of `UITableViewCell`. But that doesn't work because it returns (0, 0, 320, 44). The Y value shouldn't be zero because obviously the cell is not at the top of the screen.

According to the view hierarchy, this is the intended behaviour, because the superview of a table cell is apparently this `UITableViewWrapperView`, not the table view:

[image]

while the table view is this:

[image]

So is there a method/property that can get me a `CGRect` that represents the frame of the table view cell in the coordinate space of the table view?

I think there is a function that can convert a `CGRect` in a coordinate space to another. But I forgot its name and how to use it. I don't know whether it is helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Please use below code

```
let rectOfCell= tableView.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
let rectOfCellInSuperview = tableView.convertRect(rectOfCell, toView: tableView.superview)
```

Comment: What is `rectOfCellInTableView`? Did you mean `rectOfCell`?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The `convertRect` method does not seem to take the height of the section headers into consideration. The rect is a bit higher than the table cell. i.e. has some -y offset.

Comment: Then you can  try to get rect for section and then add y + (heightOfCell)(indexPath.row) of cell to get the cell y position.

Comment: It works, but I kinda want a cleaner solution because I am kinda bad at maths. I'll wait a little while for a better answer.

Comment: tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)